# Pyspark aggregation function with arrays in columns

Tags: python, pyspark, aggregate

Imagining that I have a dataframe like the below

```
+--------------------+----+
|                 _c5| _c1|
+--------------------+----+
|          [comments]|  id|
|[Daniel, is, real...|1191|
|[Daniel, is, the,...|1771|
|[We, had, such, a...|1989|
|                null|null|
+--------------------+----+
```

I know I can `df.groupby("_c1").agg(F.collect_list("_c5"))` to groupby the id and then return an array of arrays in the _c5 column, but wondering if there was a possibly more memory efficient way of doing this when I have millions of values in an array.

Does collect_list actually collect the list into memory? Ideally I'd end up with a flattened, distinct list in the _c5 column, instead of an array of arrays.

Comment: If you're using spark 2.4+ you can use [`flatten`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.flatten) and [`array_distinct`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.array_distinct). Something like `df.groupBy("_c1").agg(F.array_distinct(F.flatten(F.collect_list("_c5"))))`

Comment: @pault but I'd always need to collect_list before using the flatten/distinct combo?